# I want to take photo of moon with my mobile camera?

Tags: night, moon, mobile

I tried taking pic of moon with my mobile camera, i tried auto mode and manual mode also. but its not clear. what are different option or addition tool required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take photos of planets with smartphone?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/99963/how-to-take-photos-of-planets-with-smartphone)

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have a multi-camera phone with a very strong telephoto option, the moon is much too small in the frame to give usable results even with modern, high resolution sensors.

A single camera phone will have something like a 24mm or 28mm equivalent lens. Which will make the moon look tiny in your frame - digital zoom will only help you magnify it a few times before you run out of resolution reserves.

DSLR/DSLM/superzoom users use 300mm to 1000mm equivalent lenses for good moon pictures...

Comment: I have moto g5s+ phone which is dual camera, Will this phone work?

Comment: This is a main+selfie phone... I did mean the kind with 3 or more main cameras....

Comment: which phone would you suggest me to buy which is good for photography , I cannot afford a DSLR camera at this moment.

Comment: Unlikely to find a phone (unless you rent it with a contract) that is better at moon shots and cheaper than a basic secondhand DSLR with a basic long focus prime...

Answer (score 2):

It's sort of unexpected but the moon is really small.  Phone cameras are not really useful here; you want equivalent focal lengths of 600mm to maybe 2000mm.  You do not need or want a DSLR for that: older superzoom or hyperzoom cameras with small sensor (the current standard for "small sensor" tends to be 1/2.3") behind a long lens will do the trick and will neither bust your budget (specifically since you are thinking about buying a used smartphone insteaed) nor your arm strength.

Of course, mounting a more ordinary camera (assuming you get it to mount) behind an ordinary telescope will allow you to do astrophotography reasonably well.  Like with mounting a camera on a microscope, being able to use general purpose optics rather than something specifically fit to the camera may give you a solution without special purpose pricing.

Answer (score 2):

You should try manual focus, the first time I tried to take a pic of the moon with my iPhone the moon was blurry until I figured out the autofocus was not working, you need to focus at the infinite, try to focus on a street light that is at least 5 meters away

Answer (score 1):

**Instruction may vary as each version of Android may be slightly different:**

- On the left taskbar you'll see a JPG icon. Tap thereon and it'll switch to RAW JPG. this may allow corrections to be made to the image after the image has been taken.
- Change the Exposure Value by tapping the EV option on screen and selecting a coffee exposure.
- Select the ISO option and choose a worth of between 80 and 100.
- Increase the shutter speed, using the S option on screen, and choose the longest option. this may take longer to require the photo so staying still is crucial .
- Take your shot! Once you're pleased with the way your image appears on the screen, click the circular capture button at the bottom of the app.

Comment: Thank you, i will try and show u result.

Comment: what's a "coffee exposure" and why would a long exposure time be necessary for a moon shot?